# How do I know a patch is safe?

Tags: mods

I find the idea of downloading and running a patch a bit worrisome. I've never heard of people using patches to distribute malware, but there's no reason they couldn't. For instance, I'm trying to run Voobly off of a Steam AoE2 game, and there's [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209131/age-of-empires-ii-hd-on-voobly) that has a link to a patch, and it's on a website that has no connection (AFAIK) to Voobly or Steam. On the one hand, it sseems a bit paranoid to think that whoever wrote that patch did it get malware on m computer, but on the other hand downloading and installing programs from random webpages seems a bit risk.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
However I played long time with 1.0c (and 1.0e) patch, because on 1.0 there were some known hacks. You can just download AOE 2 from any torrent site or from voobly (but their links seems to not working). But you risk same as downloading it from [www.aoccs.net](http://www.aoccs.net/)
If you want to be sure, just play on steam, there is no big difference.